# Django - Save modelformset data to session in CBV

Tags: python, django, forms, django-generic-views

**Goal**: I'm trying to save modelformset data to session. I have a view where a same set of form fields need to be filled out for items chosen from a checkbox in a previous view.

**Problem**: My modelformset somehow returns only the last set of inputs after cleaned_data (but I can see all inputs in request.POST).

I don't get validation or any kind of errors (If I switch the inputs, the input that was passing before does not pass cleaned_data)

request.POST

```
<QueryDict: {'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['#abbr', '#abbr', '#abbr'], 'form-0-pd_month': ['8', '5', '7'], 'form-0-pd_day': ['28', '28', '28'], 'form-0-pd_year': ['2017', '2017', '2017'], 'form-0-var': ['t1', 't2', 't3'], 'form-0-id': ['', '', '']}>
```

cleaned_data

```
{'pd': datetime.date(2017, 7, 28), 'var': 't3', 'id': None}
```

I checked

- [In a Django Formset being returned in a Post, all Forms are showing all fields changed even though none have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174686/in-a-django-formset-being-returned-in-a-post-all-forms-are-showing-all-fields-c)
- [Django save only first form of formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609332/django-save-only-first-form-of-formset)
- [Django formset only adding one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959989/django-formset-only-adding-one-form)
- [Only last label input value being returned in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056480/only-last-label-input-value-being-returned-in-django)
- and 100 more

as well as Django doc but none of these work for me.

**Code**: I pasted as minimal code as possible without compromising the big picture.

views.py

```
#checklist view
class VView(CreateView):
    form_class = VForm
    template_name = 'b/ve.html'

    def post(self, request):
        form = VForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            val = form.cleaned_data['ve']
            name = []
            for obj in val:
                temp = dict(V.LIB).get(obj)
                name.append(temp)

            request.session['val'] = val
            request.session['name'] = name
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/b/d/')


#fill in same fields for each selection in VView
class DView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'b/d.html'

    def get(self, request):
        name = request.session['name']
        formset = VarDFormSet()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'name': name, 'formset': formset})

    def post(self, request):
        formset = VarDFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                var = form.cleaned_data['var']
                pd = form.cleaned_data['pd']
                pd = pd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

            request.session['var'] = var
            request.session['pd'] = pd
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/b/loc/')
```

models.py

```
class V(models.Model):
    LIB = [
        #list of lists
        ]
    checklist = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = LIB)

class Setup(models.Model):
    ve = models.ManyToManyField(V)
    var = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null = True)
    pd = models.DateField(null = True)
```

forms.py

```
class VForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Setup
        fields = ['ve']


class VarDForm(ModelForm):
    #set initial value for pd

    class Meta:
        model = Setup
        fields = ['pd', 'var']

VarDFormSet = modelformset_factory(Setup, fields=('pd', 'var'), form=VarDForm)
```

DView template

```
<form method='post' action=''>
{{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset  %}
        {% for obj in name %}

        <h2> {{obj}} </h2>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}

        {% endfor %}        
    {% endfor %}

<input type='submit' value='次へ'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question about formsets. You have multiple values, and you iterate through them, but then in each iteration you assign the values to the same local variables. So each variable is overwritten in each iteration, leaving them both with the last values only.

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but why can't you simply assign the value of `formset.cleaned_data` to an element in the session?

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time!! I'm trying to save a list of inputs for each field (i.e. pd, var) to the session, so that I can correlate them with inputs from other views before saving to DB. I understand that the way the code looks right now, I seem like doing neither.   
Here, my main goal was to check if cleaned_data is really passing the data in request.POST. So, I actually had a `print(form.cleaned_data['var'])` right below `for form in formset:` (which I foolishly edited out) and it's only printing last input after all iterations (see cleaned_data above).

Comment: Regarding your solution, I tried `for form in formset: #request.session['var'] = form.cleaned_data['var']  #print(request.session['var'])` (where  # is just a memo for linebreak) and it still gives the last input. I also checked how many times `for form in formset:` is looping and it's giving me 1. So, probably something is wrong with my `formset`, but I don't know what. Could you give me some directions on where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: But that's just doing the same thing as in your original code, except using the session directly rather than a local variable. If you have multiple values, you need to store them in some kind of list. Or, as I said, use the *formset* `cleaned_data` as that already gives you a list.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this entire formset concept. Just to make sure _formset_ `cleaned_data` is something that looks like `[form.cleaned_data for form in formset]`? If that's the case, it's still returning the last input ...

Comment: You should print it in your view; it will be something like `[{'pd': 'foo', 'var': 1}, {'pd': 'bar', 'var': 2}]`. Forgetting formsets completely, you should work out how you want to represent a structure like that in your session.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not being clear here. I had already printed it and it only returns `[{'pd': datetime.date(2017, 7, 28), 'var': 't3', 'id': None}]`, which is the _last input_ in request,POST: `<QueryDict: {'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1'], ... 'form-0-pd_month': ['8', '5', '7'], 'form-0-pd_day': ['28', '28', '28'], 'form-0-pd_year': ['2017', '2017', '2017'], 'form-0-var': ['t1', 't2', 't3'], 'form-0-id': ['', '', '']}>`. Is there something wrong with my `DView template` that's causing this?

Comment: The code you have here wouldn't give that result. Are you posting this via Ajax? Or are you doing something different on the template (hard-coding the field names, for example)?

Comment: No, I'm not doing any of those. The posted `DView template` is all there is to it. Is it possible that `VarDFormSet` in `forms.py` isn't properly setup in the first place?